# How to write a random vote generator in Python

Tags: python

So I have to write a code that prompts a user to input a number which is the number of voters and then those voters are distributed by percentages to 3 candidates. On top of that, I have to import a random number and if that number is >= 5 that vote counts as a fraud and gets subtracted. Also if they are bribed the vote goes to a different candidate. Finally, I need to make a pie chart using turtle to display the results. This is all I have so far:

```
import turtle, random

voters = int(input("Enter the # of would-be voters here: "))

numIM = 0
numCA = 0
numSM = 0

while (voters > 0):
    numIM = random.randint(0,100)
    if numIM <= 5:
        voters -= 1
    numCA = random.randint(0, 100)
    if numCA <= 5:
        voters -= 1
    numSM = random.randint(0, 100)
    if numSM <= 5:
        voters -= 1
```

The confusing part to me is this:
Determine which hero the voter will vote for. Again, you will use a random number between 1 and 100 to determine which hero they voted for. The heroes have the following chance of being picked:

Iron Man - 34%
Captain America - 33%
Spiderman - 33%

Comment: What determines a bribe and who the vote goes to?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `random.choices` it takes argument `weights` that you can assign to each item.

```
import random

voters = int(input('Enter the number of would be voters: '))

numIM = 0
numCA = 0
numSM = 0

while (voters > 0):
    vote = random.choices(['im', 'ca', 'sm'], [.34, .33, .33])
    r = random.randint(0, 100)    
    if 'im' in vote:  
        if r <=5:
            numIM -= 1
        else:
            numIM += 1
    elif 'ca' in vote:
        if r <=5:
            numCA -= 1
        else:
            numCA += 1
    elif 'sm' in vote:
        if r <=5:
            numSM -= 1
        else:
            numSM += 1
    voters -= 1

print(numIM, numCA, numSM)
```

> ```
> Enter the number of would be voters: 100
> 25 40 29
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you have is that the three randoms have no guarantee of adding up to 100.

This is a modified version, but efficient.

```
import random

voters = int(input('Enter the number of would be voters: '))
voteTypes = {"im":0,"ca":0,"sm":0}
cands = [cand for cand in voteTypes.keys()]
for a in range(voters):
    recip = random.choice(cands)
    voteTypes[recip] +=1
```